# How to give restricted access to GWT application among several computers from different regions

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I want to run a GWT application which is to be accessed from n number of computers from different regions.For my requirement I want to restrict the access of that particular application.
I can track the IPs of the machines used and match those with the registered IPs present in my database.Access will be denied for the users on the login page(even after providing valid username and password) if the IP is not present in my database.But for handling large number of computers from different regions it may create an issue as the machines may be replaced and I have to update my database frequently.

Is there any other efficient way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i didn't get the question correctly.
In case you want to restrict users from certain countries to access your application you can obtain their location using one of these approaches (or combine both):

- [Get user's region using HTML5 Geolocation API](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)
- Use an [IP to Geolocation rest service](https://freegeoip.net/?q=213.91.208.200)

So instead of storing IPs you'll end up just storing a list of countries/regions which are legal. Also be aware of proxy users :)